# Box-shadow not appearing on <header> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a `<header>` tag and I want it to have a box-shadow to improve it's appearance. However, the box-shadow doesn't show up. I was using `<div>` at first and it was working.

I thought `<header>` is more semantically correct so I used it instead.

Here's my markup: 
**menubar.php**

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Maintenance <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="?goto=country">Countries</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?goto=province">Provinces</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?goto=mobile">Mobile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?goto=customer">Customer</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="?goto=logout">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Here's my CSS for the `<header>` tag:

```
header{
       background: #fee;
       height: 120px;
       padding: 20px;
       border-bottom: 5px solid #f53301;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 16px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 12px 16px -6px black;
       box-shadow: 0 12px 16px -6px black;
      }
```

A screenshot (if it can help):
[image: Screenshot]

I hope someone can help me with it. Cheers!

**Update:** 
I tried it on jsfiddle and it's working just fine. I know it will work, but unfortunately, it isn't working.
I'm testing it on Chrome and IE11 (with or without EmulateIE8)

Comment: What is the problem? It is working fine for me..check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eC48k/10/

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/352na/)

Comment: It isn't working for me. I'm using it both on Chrome and IE11.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it's working fine. Check whether it is working for you in the fiddle posted on the other comments.

Comment: It is. I even tested it myself and it is working. I know it's supposed to work, but I provided a screenshot for you to know I ain't trolling.

Comment: it is working or it isn't???

Comment: It isn't working on my actual project, but is working in fiddle or everything else.

Comment: In that case, it is probably to do with code somewhere else interfering, like a tag left open.

Comment: I'm mimicking XHTML rules so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It's working in my Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 m.

Comment: It is working when it is standalone. But when I have it in my website, it doesn't render correctly.

Comment: Are you using any code (html, css, jquery) that you didn't write? Odds are there's a global style somewhere in your code preventing the shadow.

Comment: Nope, I don't have any plugins installed except for Modernizr.

Answer (score 2):

Apply position relative and z-index; or Increase margin-bottom till you see the shadow`position:relative;z-index:10`

Comment: i would LOVE to know why this solves the problem. I just tried it and it works, but i cant even begin to understand why this should make a difference. How do you know this?